# In vue js, @change event is calling twice because of v-model, but i need both @change event and v-model but it should call only once

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

> <v-file-input
> v-model="files"
> @change="data($event)"
> :error="error" >
>
> ```
>     async data(file) {
>                 if (!file) {
>                 const documentEntityId = this.$store.getters["userData/userData"][this.entityCode] ?
>                     this.$store.getters["userData/userData"][this.entityCode].entityId :
> undefined;
>                 if (documentEntityId) {
>                     const deleteItem = await CommonService.deleteDocument(`${documentEntityId}`);
>                     this.$store.getters["userData/userData"][this.entityCode] = {};
>                     store.dispatch("userData/setUserData", {
>                         fileType: undefined,
>                         file: undefined
>                     });
>                     store.dispatch("userData/setUserData", {
>                         fileType: undefined,
>                         file: undefined
>                     });
>                     this.files = [];
>                     return;
>                 }
> ```
>
> > data , initially recieved as undefined, means if we click x to delete document, then once i changed this.files = [] before return. it is
> > coming out of the function and again it is calling @change event
> > because of v-model. please help me.

Comment: Why do you think you need both `v-model` and `change` event? You can use either `v-model` alone or the `change` event and set it with `:value`.

Comment: for some scenario i need both, eg:-a) i need change event to call one function at the time of file select, b) later if i go to the different screen and come back, for this i need v-model to render previous data to the screen.                                                                                      As you told, i tried with :value and @change , but it is also calling change event twice. but my scenario was,, (v-model) files = [] , this one i nee to change to files= some value, but that should not call change again twice.

Comment: You can use `v-model` only and leave the updating of the array to the component. Add a `watcher` to be notified when the array changes and you will not need the `change` event. In the watcher you can perform validation to not handle the same change twice if the component is so chatty.

Comment: I agree to the others: use a watcher and trigger your change event in the watcher code.